# hierarchical mapping of multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `mapping_df` and `df2`.I want to map `df2` with `mapping_df` In both the dataframes , `cluster_1` is associated with `cluster_2` and `cluster_2` is associated with `cluster_3`. Its a kind of hierarchical clustering.

```
mapping_df
```

[image]

```
df2
```

[image]

I want to map `mapping_df['cluster_1']` with `df2['cluster_1']` and get the corresponding `cluster_label1`.
One mapping for `cluster_label1` is done then it should move to `cluster_2` within `cluster_1` and map the corresponding `cluster_label2`.Similarly for `cluster_label3`.

My desired output is :

[image]

Currently I am converting `mapping_df` into three parts :

```
mapping_df_L1 =mapping_df[['cluster_1',cluster_label1']]
mapping_df_L2 =mapping_df[['cluster_2',cluster_label2']]
mapping_df_L3 =mapping_df[['cluster_3',cluster_label3']]
```

and then trying to merge each `mapping_df_L1` ,`mapping_df_L2`,`mapping_df_L3`, with `df2`.
But I am not able to handle hierarchical mapping.

Comment: If I understood your right shouldn't a right merge do the trick?

Comment: I tried merging, but as i mentioned, mapping should happen in hierarchical form, it should map `cluster_1` and then within `cluster_1` it should map `cluster_2` and then withing `cluster_2` it should map `cluster_3` with their respective `labels`.

Comment: It is not clear how to map row 2 of *df2*. It contains *1, 1, 1*
but *mapping_df* does not contain any row with such 3 values
as *cluster1*, *cluster2* and *cluster3*.
Another hint: Replace pictures of your DataFrames with **text**.
I have plenty of more interesting things to do instead of rewriting
the content from your pictures.

Comment: Take also look at row 3 of *df2* (1, 2, 0).
Note that *cluster_1 == 1*. So why *cluster_label_3* has a value from *cluster_1 == 2*?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a straight forward inner join.

```py
a = np.array(np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [0,1,2], [0,1])).reshape(3,-1)
a = [[l1 for l1 in a[0]], [f"label{l1}" for l1 in a[0]],
 [l2 for l2 in a[1]], [f"label{a[0][i]}_{l2+1}" for i, l2 in enumerate(a[1])],
 [l3 for l3 in a[2]], [f"label{a[0][i]}_{a[1][i]+1}_{l3+1}" for i, l3 in enumerate(a[2])],
]
col = {f"cluster_{i//2+1}" if i%2==0 else f"cluster_label_{i//2+1}":a[i] 
       for i in range(6)}
mapping_df = pd.DataFrame(col)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"cluster_1":[1,1,1,2,2], 
                    "cluster_2":[0,1,2,0,1], 
                    "cluster_3":[0,1,0,0,1]})
df2_m = df2.merge(mapping_df, on=["cluster_1","cluster_2","cluster_3"], how="inner")

print(f"""mapping_df rows:{len(mapping_df)} head:
{mapping_df.head().to_string(index=False)}
df2:
{df2.to_string(index=False)}
df2_m
{df2_m.to_string(index=False)}""")
```

**output**

```
mapping_df rows:18 head:
 cluster_1 cluster_label_1  cluster_2 cluster_label_2  cluster_3 cluster_label_3
         1          label1          0        label1_1          0      label1_1_1
         1          label1          0        label1_1          1      label1_1_2
         2          label2          0        label2_1          0      label2_1_1
         2          label2          0        label2_1          1      label2_1_2
         3          label3          0        label3_1          0      label3_1_1
df2:
 cluster_1  cluster_2  cluster_3
         1          0          0
         1          1          1
         1          2          0
         2          0          0
         2          1          1
df2_m
 cluster_1  cluster_2  cluster_3 cluster_label_1 cluster_label_2 cluster_label_3
         1          0          0          label1        label1_1      label1_1_1
         1          1          1          label1        label1_2      label1_2_2
         1          2          0          label1        label1_3      label1_3_1
         2          0          0          label2        label2_1      label2_1_1
         2          1          1          label2        label2_2      label2_2_2
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to add text tabels for *cluster_1* and *cluster_2*:

```
df2a = df2.set_index(['cluster_1', 'cluster_2']).join(
    mapping_df.loc[:, :'cluster_label2'].set_index(['cluster_1', 'cluster_2']))\
    .reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
   cluster_1  cluster_2  cluster_3 cluster_label1 cluster_label2
0          1          0          0         label1       label1_1
1          1          1          1         label1       label1_2
2          1          2          0         label1       label1_3
3          2          0          0         label2       label2_1
4          2          1          1         label2       label2_2
```

(don't worry about the column order).

To add text labels for *cluster_3*, a more sophisticated procedure is
required, namely after *set_index* we must drop duplicates in the index:

```
map_df = mapping_df.iloc[:, [0, 4, 5]].set_index(['cluster_1', 'cluster_3'])
map_df = map_df.loc[~map_df.index.duplicated(keep='first')];
```

A the only thing remaining to do is to join and reorder columns:

```
result = df2a.set_index(['cluster_1', 'cluster_3']).join(map_df).reset_index()\
    [['cluster_1', 'cluster_label1', 'cluster_2', 'cluster_label2', 'cluster_3',
      'cluster_label3']]
```

The result is:

```
   cluster_1 cluster_label1  cluster_2 cluster_label2  cluster_3  cluster_label3
0          1         label1          0       label1_1          0      label1_1_1 
1          1         label1          2       label1_3          0      label1_1_1 
2          1         label1          1       label1_2          1      label1_3_3 
3          2         label2          0       label2_1          0      label2_1_1 
4          2         label2          1       label2_2          1      label2_3_2
```